# Jumbotron not adjusting with screen/browser size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with BootStrap and facing an issue with Jumbotrons.
There are 2 divs on my page, the second one should suppose to take the remaining screen size. But when i am changing the browser height and width it's not adjusting accordingly as in the height of the div is not getting adjusted as it should.

HTML :

```
    <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo1">
    <div class="container">
    <h1>Some Txt.</h1>
    </div>        
    </div>

    <div class="jumbotron" id="jumbo2">

    <p>

        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuri.
        </p>
    <div class="container-fluid">

    <section id="gly">  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true" id="dwnarrow"></span>
        </section>  

        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
     html,body
    {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }


    #jumbo1
    {
        height:auto;
    }

    #jumbo2
    {

        padding: 0px;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    #gly
    {
        text-align: center;

        margin-top: 300px;
    }
```

Can anyone tell what am I doing wrong here???

Comment: what do you mean by "doesn't adjust"?

Comment: the 2 div content is not getting properly displayed.If you look at the glyphicon it should be at 300px margin from top of the div tough that works when the browser size it maximum but when i toggle with the browser it shifts and "DOES NOT WRAPS INSIDE THE PARENT DIV(jumbo2)" to make it responsive.

Comment: so you want your arrow going just a bit lower than the height of the fold?

Comment: im referring this [http://3str.net/d/tinyone-psd-html/]   , if you can have a look at it that be great , thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
html, body{
  height:100%;
}

#jumbo1 {
  height:100%;
}

.container-fluid {
  text-align:center;
}

#gly {
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:20px;
}
```

Try it directly in your page.

Comment: thanks a lot , that's exactly how i wanted , but the glyphicon is not coming in center?

Comment: with width 100% it exceeds the screen size? :/

Comment: now is better. i suggest to add a class like "centered" to container-fluid, then apply text-align center to the centered class.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `max-height: 100%;` for `#jubmo2`

Comment: second div should take the remaining screen size

Comment: try height: auto instead of max-height: 100%